# ORA-14075: partition maintenance operations may only be performed on partitioned indices

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have several Oracle table that each of them is partitioned on "date" column. For example, I have a partitioned Oracle table with these columns:

```
id,date,customer_id,code,name,last_name
```

It has primary key on "id,date" also it has been partitioned on "date" field. Moreover,I define two separate indices on "customer_id" and "code".
I have a Python program that I must make each index of the table unusable and after loading data to every tables,select all indices of the table with this query and rebuild each index for partition of current date.The code is in following:

```
       def rebuild_index_partition(self,date, table_name):
            query = "(select partition_name pname from all_tab_partitions where table_name like upper('%{0}%') and " \
            "to_date(trim('''' from regexp_substr(extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select high_value from all_tab_partitions " \
            "where table_name='''||table_name||''' and table_owner = '''||table_owner||''' and partition_name = '''||partition_name||'''')," \
            "'//text()'),'''.*?''')),'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')= to_date({1}, 'yyyymmdd', 'nls_calendar=persian') + 1)".format(
        table_name, date)
            df = pd.read_sql(query,self.conn)
            pname = df.loc[0, 'PNAME']
            index_query = f'''select distinct a.index_name index_name from all_ind_columns a, all_indexes b where a.index_name=b.index_name and a.table_name = upper('{table_name}') '''
            df_index = pd.read_sql(index_query,self.conn)
            list_index = df_index['INDEX_NAME'].tolist()
            for i in list_index:
                rebuild_index = "alter index {0} rebuild partition {1}".format(i, pname)
                self.execute(rebuild_index)
       return
```

The problem is when **rebuild** index is run, it gives this error:

```
   ORA-14075: partition maintenance operations may only be performed on partitioned indices
   14075. 00000 -  "partition maintenance operations may only be performed on partitioned indices"
      *Cause:    Index named in ALTER INDEX partition maintenance operation
       is not partitioned, making a partition maintenance operation,
       at best, meaningless
     *Action:   Ensure that the index named in ALTER INDEX statement
       specifying a partition maintenance operation is, indeed,
       partitioned
```

This is because Primary key is not partitioned. I don't know how to make Primary key partitioned,local index.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the `alter index abc rebuild` for *non*-partitioned indexes, and `alter index abc rebuild partition xyz` for *partitioned* indexes (looping on every partition). Here's a PL/SQL block that would take care of all of it. You can adapt what you see here to your programming environment if you'd prefer to do the looping in your client environment, but this illustrates the approach:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_index IN (SELECT index_owner,index_name
                      FROM all_indexes
                     WHERE table_name = upper('{table_name}')
                       AND status = 'UNUSABLE') -- partitioned indexes will say N/A and so be skipped here
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX "'||rec_index.index_owner||'"."'||rec_index.index_name||'" REBUILD';
  END LOOP;
   
  FOR rec_index IN (SELECT ip.index_owner,
                           ip.index_name, 
                           ip.partition_name
                      FROM all_ind_partitions ip,
                           all_indexes i
                     WHERE i.table_name = upper('{table_name}')
                       AND i.owner = ip.index_owner
                       AND i.index_name = ip.index_name
                       AND ip.status = 'UNUSABLE')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX "'||rec_index.index_owner||'"."'||rec_index.index_name||'" REBUILD PARTITION "'||rec_index.partition_name||'"';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But if I could make a recommendation, if you are doing daily maintenance and invalidating global indexes, you should reevaluate whether those should in fact be global indexes. You'd be better off with *all* indexes as local. The only exception is if you have high-frequency lookups against a unique or near-unique value and you have a very large number of partitions. In that case you'd need to keep it global. But if the column isn't near-unique or if the frequency of lookups on it are low or the number of partitions is relatively small, it may be worth making it local to avoid the unnecessary full-index rebuild each time.

**Update**: to assist with making your PK local as requested, if you created the table like this:

```
create table tmp1 (col1 integer, constraint pk_tmp1 primary key (col1)) partition by . . .;
```

Then the index that enforces the constraint is implicitly bound to the constraint and will drop when you drop the constraint. So, simply drop and re-add the constraint with the `using index` clause:

```
alter table tmp1 drop constraint pk_tmp1;
alter table tmp1 add constraint pk_tmp1 primary key (col1) using index local;
```

If the index was created and constraint added later, like this:

```
create table tmp1 (col1 integer) partition by . . .;
create unique index pk_tmp1 on tmp1(col1);
alter table tmp1 add constraint pk_tmp1 primary key (col1) using index pk_tmp1;
```

Then you have a separate index and constraint and have to work on them separately. You would then need to drop the constraint, drop the index, recreate the index, then re-add the constraint:

```
alter table tmp1 drop constraint pk_tmp1;
drop index pk_tmp1;
create unique index pk_tmp1 on tmp1(col1) local;
alter table tmp1 add constraint pk_tmp1 primary key (col1) using index pk_tmp1;
```

If you wished to drop the table completely and recreate it (it's unnecessary to do this and causes data loss), you can do:

```
drop table tmp1;     
create table tmp1 (col1 integer, constraint pk_tmp1 primary key (col1) using index local) partition by . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since I have a large table and I have to work on each partition in each query;so I need to define primary key as a local index. Would you please guide me how to define that?

Comment: @M_Gh -  Extract the DDL for the index, drop the index (if there's a constraint defined you will need to drop the constraint first), then add the keyword `LOCAL` to the end of the index DDL and recreate it. If you dropped a constraint you may want to then re-add it.

Comment: the first query is wrong. **ORA-00904: "TABLE_NAME": invalid identifier**

Comment: @M_Gh, I took that from your code, which uses your programming language's conventions, assumnig that you'd be submitting this block from that environment and that it was capable of substituting placeholders in PL/SQL just like you showed it doing in SQL. If that's not the case or if you are running this in another environment you'll need to remove the {} and put in a literal table name, or work with your programming conventions to bind the name in the appropriate manner. That's not an Oracle thing.

Comment: I change that and run this query in SQL Developer: ***(SELECT * FROM all_ind_partitions WHERE table_name = upper('table_name') AND status = 'UNUSABLE')*** then receive this error: ***ORA-00904: "TABLE_NAME": invalid identifier***

Comment: **all_ind_partitions** does not have **table_name** column.

Comment: @M_Gh, sorry about that. Edited.